# Получить содержимое элемента по названию свойста

Tags: python, html, request, re

```
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
```

получаю содержимое страницы вот таким образом

на странице есть элемент

```
<span _ngcontent-app-desktop-c291="" class="santa-text-red-500"> 821 </span>
```

как я могу получить этот элемент не по классу а по  `_ngcontent-app-desktop-c291=""` ?

Answer (score 0):

Данную задачу можно решить с помощью библиотеки bs4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

element = soup.select_one("[_ngcontent-app-desktop-c291='']")
```

В переменной 'element' находится необходимый элемент.